# Styling angular mat-select on condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using `<mat-select>` and I would like to have some of the options with a bold style when a condition is true.

Currently, the options are bold in the dropdown choices, but once the option is selected, the style is not applied to the selection in the text field.

How can I apply the style to the text field after the selection ?

Here is a code sample :

```
<mat-form-field>
          <mat-label><span translate="entities.annexe"></span></mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)]="p.annexe" formControlName="annexe">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let annexe of annexesEnums()" [value]="getNameFromValue(annexe)">
              <span [style.font-weight]="annexe != 'Default' ? 'bold' : 'normal'">{{annexe}}</span>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Something else is happening with your code that you haven't shown. `<span [style.font-weight]="'bold'">` works fine for selected or non-selected list items. Do you have any other style, maybe globally defined?

Comment: '!=' should be replaced by '!=='

Comment: That's not it - this works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2v4nt7?file=app/select-overview-example.html

Comment: If you want that style to get applied to the selected value after the selection, you will have to apply it to select itself. Applying  [style.font-weight]="annexe != 'Default' ? 'bold' : 'normal'" to mat-select should do it. Please refer - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgnq4k?file=app/select-overview-example.ts

Comment: @G.Tranter your stackblitz shows exactly what i'm facing, indeed, it is bold in the dropdown, but I would like it to stay bold in the input, when the select is no longer focused.

Comment: @Abhay That doesn't make any sense. The example I posted above works fine - no style is applied to `mat-select`.

Comment: @Ellone - that's the missing information I referred to. Your post specifically stated "make the dropdown style persist" - the text field is not part of the "dropdown" and is not a `mat-option` element. Please revise your post.

Comment: You are correct @Abhay, thanks, I just had to apply the `[style]` to the `<mat-select>` as well replacing `annexe` with `p.annexe`

Comment: @G.Tranter sorry if we misunderstood each other, what I meant is that the style was present in the dropdown, but not outside, in the input, once the selection is made, and I wanted it to be kept.

Comment: I have added that as answer for future viewers to easily get that

Comment: @Ellone no worries - I understood you just fine - you just didn't explain the problem properly in your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that style to get applied to the selected value after the selection, you will have to apply it to select itself. Applying [style.font-weight]="annexe != 'Default' ? 'bold' : 'normal'" to mat-select should do it. It would be better to take it to common place in component and refer it from there.

Please refer -https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgnq4k?file=app/select-overview-example.ts

Comment: What happened to `!==`? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apply the style to both the `mat-select` and `mat-option`. For `mat-select`, you can check the value of the selection using the `selected` property. You can apply the style using template logic - you don't need to use the `selectionChange` event if you don't want to:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgnq4k-743d3o?file=app/select-overview-example.html

```
<mat-select #select [style.font-weight]="select.value != 'default' ? 'bold' : 'normal'">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" 
      [style.font-weight]="food.value != 'default' ? 'bold' : 'normal'">
    {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your span with below :

`<span [style.font-weight]="annexe !== 'Default' ? 'bold' : 'normal'">{{annexe}}</span>`

Comment: You are just missing '=' operator

Comment: While that _is_ better code, it doesn't help in this situation as the `!=` comparison should be sufficient. See this - works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2v4nt7?file=app/select-overview-example.html.

Comment: Sometimes this issue occurs. Also would be more great to know what 'annexesEnums()' is returning here. I believe this function is continuously returning an Array which could create issues. I repeat as I don't know what it is returning.